# Electric Field at surface/side of cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I know I can use Gauss's law to find the Electric Field inside and outside the cylinder very easily. We can select Gaussian surfaces for different cases (i.e. $r \lt R$ and $r \gt R$, where $R$ is the radius of the cylinder and $r$ is the radius of Gaussian surface).

But I want to know Electric fields at the bottom and the upper circular surface of the cylinder.

Edit: Charge of the cylinder can be anything ($\lambda, \sigma, \rho$). For clarification there is one cylinder and I want to find the E field on the top and bottom circular surfaces rather than inside or outside.

Comment: Can you please edit this to make it clearer what cylinders and surfaces you're talking about, and the charge distribution?

Comment: A little bit, but now the problem seems much more complicated. It sounds like what you're talking about is a finite-length cylinder, in which case you can't use Gauss' law the way you describe.

Comment: @Jordan Why can't you use gauss's law on a finite length cylinder? If you were find the E field inside, rather than on the side a finite cylinder would be doable.

Comment: You can use Gauss' law on a finite-length cylinder, you just can't make the assumption that the electric field is of constant magnitude in the radial direction over the surface of that cylinder, so you'd need to do some rather messy math.

Comment: @Jordan For practical purposes let us assume it is an infinite cylinder, how would you do it then? Thanks

Comment: If it's an infinite cylinder with a charge density which only depends on the distance from the center then by symmetry arguments the electric field is pointed in the radial direction only. When you integrate over the caps of your cylinder for Gauss' law the oriented area is orthogonal to the electric field, so the caps contribute nothing to the integral. However, this argument fails for a finite cylinder, since there will clearly be some electric field along the axial direction.

Comment: @Jordan : for an infinite conductor you cannot talk about the caps, it is just senseless. Probably a singularity, we have no idea what goes on at infinity.  But for the sake of argument, it would be along the axis! Because each particle would be exerting a field along the axis which would add up

Comment: You just said we don't know what happens at infinity, then claimed that there would be an axial field there. I'm talking about evaluating the field not at infinity by using Gauss' law in the same manner as is usually done with an infinite line charge. The caps are for a finite surface of integration around part of an infinite charged cylinder.

Comment: Well you should also clarify that whether the given cylinder is solid cylinder or a hollow cylinder depending upon which we can select the surface charge density ($\sigma$) or volume charge density ($\rho$)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$K=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}$

Using elemental rings in disc we can get the Electric field at point P.

$dE = \frac{Kdq}{r^2}$ where $dq = \sigma.2\pi xdx $

Integrating from 0 to R we get

$E = \frac{Kqr}{(R^2+r^2)^{3/2}}$ where $q = \sigma\pi R^2$
$  = $

Using this in the cylinder

$dE = \frac{Kqx}{(x^2+R^2)^{3/2}}$ where $q = \rho\pi R^2dx$

Integrating this field from 0 to $\ell$ gives the required result.

$E = \frac{\rho R^2}{4\epsilon_0}\{\frac 1R - \frac 1{(R^2+l^2)^{3/2}}\}$
$  = \frac{\rho R}{4\epsilon_0}\{1 - \frac 1{R(1+\frac{l^2}{R^2})^{3/2}}\} $

and for $l\to\infty$

$E = \frac{\rho R}{4\epsilon_0}$